# How can one launch an EXE into memory from a BAT file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, memory

I understand there are commands for this in certain coding languages; such as /SWAPRUN:NET to run an EXE file which is on a network shared drive and launch/run it into the local guest's memory no longer accessing the EXE from the Host.

Is it possible to do this in a bat file?

I have an EXE I wrote which I have multiple VMWare Machines accessing. When I update my EXE I only want to replace it once; so I have a shared drive with the EXE and a bat file on each VM which launches it at start up.

However; I'm getting a lot of crashes. Just randomly; and think it may be due to the fact that so many VMs are accessing the same EXE.

The EXE does not rely on any files or write any data externally that I know of; so I am just trying to figure out how to "pre-load" or perhaps transfer the EXE locally to the guest on launch, each time the system starts - then no longer using the file on the host.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the program

```
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

or

```
start c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

By default the application will run in local memory.

Comment: Ok thats the way I am currently launching my EXE. So the problem then must be with the script/EXE I wrote. Odd thing is if only 1 machine is running it, it doesnt crash. Only when multiple machines are running/launching/cycling, do I have crash issues on systems very randomly.   So once the bat file calls the exe - it no longer accesses the exe on the host?  Thanks!

Comment: Also system resources shouldnt be the issue. It's a very lightweight EXE, and I'm running VMWare Workstation 12, on a Dual E5-2697 with 128GB Ram.

Comment: The exe must be doing something to cause it to crash. Does it use the  network? Does it read or write to files?

Comment: It does use the network but only to access the web via a firefox browser; unrelated to the EXE. I'll have to play with it. I wasnt sure if the EXE was basically "accessed" as it was run. Is there any way to write a bat command to "copy" the exe to a local dir on launch. Then do the same and "copy and replace" every time it boots?  Just to see if that solves it?

Comment: Sure... put this in a batch file: `copy \\NetworkPath\program.exe c:\temp`. Note that c:\temp must exist. Replace "NetworkPath" with your path...